# How make that component shows in sidekick at once after creating page in siteadmin and click on it?

Tags: java, components, aem

I created component and I want that after creating page in siteadmin in sidekick display needed components right now.

Could show place where can i customize it?

Answer (score 4):

Selecting the allowed components in design mode, is a one time activity for each template.
Thus, by selecting the entire group instead of selecting individual components, we can make sure that components that are newly created in the same group will be added to the sidekick automatically.

There is also one other way of approaching this.
You could attach a "**updatecomponentlist**" listener to the parsys and then complete the following function, with the logic you wish to use to populate the list of components in sidekick.

To do this, within your parsys component, create a node "cq:editConfig" of type "cq:EditConfig" and then create a node "cq:listeners" of type "cq:EditListenersConfig" as child of editConfig node. The structure for the same is shown below.

```
parsys[cq:Component]
    - cq:editConfig[cq:EditConfig]
        - cq:listeners[cq:EditListenerConfig]
```

In the editListenersConfig node, add a property called "updatecomponentlist" with the value as the following function.

```
function MyHandler(cell, allowed, componentList) {
   /*The allowed param holds the array that contains the list of components that 
     are allowed for this parsys.
     You can dynamically modify this array based on your requirements. For ex.
   */
    if(/* some condition */) {
        allowed.push('/apps/geometrixx/components/text');
        allowed.push('/apps/geometrixx/components/image');
    } else {
        allowed.push('/apps/geometrixx/components/list');
        allowed.push('/apps/geometrixx/components/table');
    } 
}
```

For futher info on implementing the listener, refer [this](http://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/HowToDefineComponentListDynamically.html).

Comment: Sorry, I am learn CQ5 third day and I don't understand where I need  write same listener and which code I have to write inside the listener

Comment: I understand how to add property updatecomponentlist, but what does it mean **with the value as the following function** ?

Comment: @gstackoverflow: The function holds your logic, where you can add the list of components that needs to be available in the sidekick. Please find the updated answer.

Comment: sorry for my stupidity but your **MyHandler** gets more 2 arguments - **cell** and **componentList**. Can you show meaning of this components at this context.

Comment: Basically, the cell, allowed and componentList are the variables that are passed on to the handler when the updatecomponentlist event is triggered. That is what we have tried to capture. The cell is the cell of the editable and the componentlist is the object that will receive the final list. Kindly refer the link, you can find the details there.

Comment: Ok. thanks for help. I upvote your answer. And tomorrow, if I will have success -  I will accept.  Actually I need to investigate on practise.